# Do I need to create 2 forms to integrate a payment processing API?

Tags: php, forms, braintree

I am following the [Braintree Payments docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/javascript+php/guides/credit-cards/client-side). To set up a credit card payment method, it says that the form code looks like this:

```
<form id="checkout" action="/your/server/endpoint" method="post">
  <input data-braintree-name="number" value="4111111111111111">
  <input data-braintree-name="expiration_date" value="10/20">
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Pay">
</form>
```

But I already have a form set up that takes all of the other necessary input (it's basically a question and answer site that charges users) and submits it to the database. Where would I put the form code given by the Braintree docs? Can you nest a form inside another form? Is that a recommended practice? Should I keep the forms separate and just process the payment on another page? Ideally, I want to do the whole process on one page and maybe pull up the credit card payment method form if they select that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

According to the [working HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/forms.html#the-form-element), a `<form>` element shouldn't contain other `<form>` elements, so a nested form would actually be technically invalid HTML. With that in mind, we can safely say it's not recommended practice. :)

However, a page can contain multiple forms. Just keep in mind that due to a form's nature (that it sends data to an endpoint and loads that endpoint), you won't be able to simultaneously submit multiple forms from the same page. A common pattern is using a checkout page dedicated to collecting the payment data in a single form.

If you want to use only one page and one form, Braintree can accommodate that. The Braintree data input elements don't have to be the only elements in the form. You could, for example include input elements asking about the user's name, birthplace, or anything else. When you point `braintree.setup` to your form, it will only pay attention to the input fields that you've marked with "data-braintree-name", and all of your normal named fields will still be in your `$_POST` variable.